# Jquery Data-table Customizing page length

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I am using a datatable and wants to change the default page length providing by datatable. As mentioned in the below link
acheive
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

we can do this by

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    } );
} );
```

I am using data table by

```
var table = $('#inbox').DataTable();
```

Because i want to disable the default search & pagination provided by datatable and customizing the search on only two columns. As i have implemented according to this

```
$('#dept').keyup( function() {
    table.columns(2).search(this.value).draw();
} );

$('#type').keyup( function() {
    table
    .columns(0)
    .search(this.value)
    .draw();
} );
```

I disabled the default search, pagingation by css

```
.dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info, .dataTables_length,
    .dataTables_paginate, .paging_simple_numbers {
    display: none;
}
```

So there is no option to  provide the lengthMenu option. I want to show the 100 rows by default with no option to change the length. How can i achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried using DisplayLength property?

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "lengthChange": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 100
});
```

Comment: In that case , I'm able to apply custom search which i am using.

    $('#dept').keyup( function() {
        table.columns(2).search(this.value).draw();
    } );

    $('#type').keyup( function() {
        table
        .columns(0)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    } );

Comment: Did you mean to say your custom search is not working?

Comment: Basically i need the reference of  `var table = $('#inbox').DataTable();`
to run my custom search .

if i apply 

`$('#example').DataTable({
    "lengthChange": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 100
}); `

then my custom search will not work. I want to use custom search as well 
and want to show 100 length.

Comment: Cool... Works for me.. Thanks..!!

Comment: Sorry accidentally deleted comment.Var table = $('#tblGLGroup').DataTable({
                "lengthChange": false,
                "iDisplayLength": 100
)};

$(document).on("keyup", "#searchBox", function () {
            groupTable.column(0).search($(this).val()).draw();

});